# awk remove the rows based on another column value

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file like below which I have sorted based on the username field.

```
UserID score UserName
1234    200   Jack
5678    150   Jill
8543    200   Jill 
5678    100   John
```

I am trying to remove the rows which have the lowest score for the same usernames. So, I want to have the output as,

```
UserID score UserName
1234    200   Jack
8543    200   Jill 
5678    100   John
```

Comment: Are the rows sorted by UserName **and** score? Or could the two Jill rows be in the opposite order?

Comment: Those 2 rows are not sorted. It is sorted only based on the username column.

Comment: Is it an option for you to make the input sorted by both columns? That would make the solution much easier (to make and to understand).

Comment: What if Jill has 3 rows: do you want to keep the one highest, or remove the one lowest?

Comment: I just need to keep the highest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to sort on the score field instead:

```
$ sort -nk2 file | awk '{k[$NF]=$0} END{for (i in k){print k[i]}}'
UserID score UserName
8543    200   Jill 
1234    200   Jack
5678    100   John
```

Or, in `perl`:

```
sort -nk2 file | perl -ane '$k{$F[$#F]}=$_; END{print "$k{$_}" for keys(%k)}'
```

The `-a` flag for perl turns on auto splitting, basically it will behave like awk, and split each line on white space, saving the fields in the array `@F`. The `-n` means process the input file line, by line.

`$F[$#F]` is the last element of `@F`, so the last field: the username. `$k{$F[$#F]}=$_;` saves each line in the hash `%k` where the keys are the usernames, overwriting whatever was there before. Since we first sort the file, this means that `$k{username}` will be the highest score for that username's entry. At the end, we print each line saved in `%k`.

Comment: As long as you're sorting, use `-r` and just print the first occurrence of each name

Comment: It's difficult to give testing input in a comment thus I abused an edit. The task is to delete one, your code deletes three lines.

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes, the OP was not clear but he actually want to [keep only the highest score](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119551/awk-remove-the-rows-based-on-another-column-value/119557?noredirect=1#comment187673_119551) (which is what I had understood in the first place) so I rolled back your edit.

Comment: @Kevin why is that simpler? You would still need to parse to get only one line per username. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RahulPatil see updated answer.

Comment: @terdon thanks but still have one confusion that, hash contain two things key,pair value and we have three userid,score,username then how it's print userid

Comment: @RahulPatil the key is the username (`$F[$#F]`) and the value is the entire line (`$_`). Think of `$_` as equivalent to awk's `$0` (in this particular case).

Comment: @terdon You need to parse, but it's shorter, and no loop: `sort -nrk2 file | awk '!a[$NF]++'`

Comment: @Kevin ah, yes, clever. But that prints the header on the last line so you'd need to deal with that as well. Why don't you post an answer with this approach?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $1,$2,$3};NR!=1{if($2>a[$3]){a[$3]=$2;b[$3]=$1}}
    END{for(x in a){print b[x],a[x],x}}' OFS="\t" file

UserID  score   UserName
1234    200     Jack
8543    200     Jill
5678    100     John
```

Or using `perl`:

```
perl -ane '$h{$F[$#F]}=[$F[$#F-1],"$_"] if $F[$#F-1] > $h{$F[$#F]}->[0];
    END{print "$h{$_}->[1]" for keys %h}' file
```

Comment: Good `awk` solution unless Jack or John happen to have a negative score ;-) Also no guarantees that input order will be retained

Comment: Yeap, if that happened, we need one more check :).

Comment: keeping one array storing $0 would be a lot simpler

Answer (score 3):

An alternate without `arrays`:

```
$ awk '
seen == $NF {line = (ishigh > $2) ? line : $0; next}
line {print line}
{seen = $NF; ishigh = $2; line = $0}
END {print line}' file
UserID score UserName
1234    200   Jack
8543    200   Jill
5678    100   John
```